# Keras InvalidErrorArgument

Tags: python, pandas, keras, keras-layer

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   user_id anime_id rating_user genre
    0   1   20  NaN Action, Comedy, Martial Arts, Shounen, Super P...
    1   3   20  8.0 Action, Comedy, Martial Arts, Shounen, Super P...
    2   5   20  6.0 Action, Comedy, Martial Arts, Shounen, Super P...
    3   6   20  NaN Action, Comedy, Martial Arts, Shounen, Super P...
    4   10  20  NaN Action, Comedy, Martial Arts, Shounen, Super P...
    5   21  20  8.0 Action, Comedy, Martial Arts, Shounen, Super P...
```

I'm trying to build a recommender system with 3 embedding but I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): indices[0,0] = 31223 is not in [0, 6816)
 [[Node: Anime-Embedding_1/Gather = Gather[Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Anime-Embedding_1/embeddings/read, Anime-Embedding_1/Cast)]]
```

My model looks like this:

the input

```
gender_id_input = Input(shape=[1], name='gender')
anime_input = Input(shape=[1],name='Anime')
user_input = Input(shape=[1],name='User')
```

my embedding

```
gender_vec = Flatten(name='FlattenGender')(Embedding(n_genres + 1, 
                                                   n_latent_factors_genre, 
                                                   name='Gender-Embedding')(gender_id_input))
gender_vec =  Dropout(0.2)(gender_vec)

#anime vec
anime_vec = Flatten(name='FlattenAnimes')(Embedding(n_animes + 1, 
                                                   n_latent_factors_anime, 
                                                   name='Anime-Embedding')(anime_input))
anime_vec = Dropout(0.2)(anime_vec)

#user vec
user_vec = Flatten(name='FlattenUsers')(Embedding(n_users + 1, 
                                                  n_latent_factors_user,
                                                  name='User-Embedding')(user_input))
user_vec = Dropout(0.2)(user_vec)

 #multi towers. #not obligated
gender_vec =  Dense(64, activation='relu')(gender_vec)
anime_vec = Dense(64, activation='relu')(anime_vec)
user_vec =  Dense(64, activation='relu')(user_vec)
```

Then I concatenate anime + gender metadata and concat with user:

```
#concatenate
anime_vecs_complete  = Concatenate()([gender_vec,anime_vec])
input_vecs = Concatenate()([user_vec, anime_vecs_complete]) 
input_vecs = Dropout(0.2)(input_vecs)

x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(input_vecs)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
y = Dense(1)(x)

model = Model(inputs=[user_input
                      ,anime_input
                      ,gender_id_input], outputs=y)
```

Then compile with adam optimizer. Here is the summary of the model:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
gender (InputLayer)             (None, 1)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Anime (InputLayer)              (None, 1)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
User (InputLayer)               (None, 1)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Gender-Embedding (Embedding)    (None, 1, 30)        79440       gender[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Anime-Embedding (Embedding)     (None, 1, 30)        213240      Anime[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
User-Embedding (Embedding)      (None, 1, 30)        150000      User[0][0]                       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
FlattenGender (Flatten)         (None, 30)           0           Gender-Embedding[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
FlattenAnimes (Flatten)         (None, 30)           0           Anime-Embedding[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
FlattenUsers (Flatten)          (None, 30)           0           User-Embedding[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_151 (Dropout)           (None, 30)           0           FlattenGender[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_152 (Dropout)           (None, 30)           0           FlattenAnimes[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_153 (Dropout)           (None, 30)           0           FlattenUsers[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_220 (Dense)               (None, 64)           1984        dropout_151[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_221 (Dense)               (None, 64)           1984        dropout_152[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_222 (Dense)               (None, 64)           1984        dropout_153[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_61 (Concatenate)    (None, 128)          0           dense_220[0][0]                  
                                                                 dense_221[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_62 (Concatenate)    (None, 192)          0           dense_222[0][0]                  
                                                                 concatenate_61[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_154 (Dropout)           (None, 192)          0           concatenate_62[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_223 (Dense)               (None, 128)          24704       dropout_154[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_155 (Dropout)           (None, 128)          0           dense_223[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_224 (Dense)               (None, 1)            129         dropout_155[0][0]                
==================================================================================================
Total params: 473,465
Trainable params: 473,465
Non-trainable params: 0
```

when it comes to fit

```
history = model.fit([train.user_id, train.anime_id, train.gender_id], 
                train.rating_user, batch_size=32, epochs=5, 
                validation_data=([
                    valid.user_id, valid.anime_id, 
                    valid.gender_id], valid.rating_user))
```

I got the error above.

P.S:

- Latent factor are fixed at 30.
- I compute `n_animes`, `n_genres`, `n_users` like this, e.g. `n_users = 
  len(df["user_id"].unique())`
- `gender_id` is a mapping result:
  `genres =  df.genre.unique()` --> `inverse_genre_map = {val:i for i,val in enumerate(genres)}` --> `df['gender_id'] = df['genre'].map(inverse_genre_map)`

I hope it's a bit understandable, if you need any complementary information ask me.

Comment: You're dealing with 3 input parameters for each sample. You do NOT need three inputs. Just input one 1 by 3 array for each sample.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, i should replace my input by a unique one to assign for each embedding ?

Comment: Create one input that is a list [gender, anime, user]. So input shape is [3]. You don't need to embed or contact. That overcomplicates a very simple problem.

Comment: I won't loose the interactions between users/items with that method ? following that list i don't embed or concat i jump into model directly ?? i'm still beginner with Keras and Deep Learning if you can write an example it will be very more understandable for me, thanks.

Comment: The neural net figures out the interactions on its own you don't need to over engineer it.

Comment: Here's just a small example. 
`model = Sequential()`
`model.add(Dense(100, input_shape=(3,)))`
`model.add(Dense(1))`. That's really all you need. If you don't want to concat all of your training data as preprocessing you can just do it in the network. `combined = Concatenate()([user_input, gender_input, anime_input])`. Just feed combined into a Dense layer. You do NOT need embeddings or every combination of 2 inputs. The network learns the correlations in the inputs on it's own.